# querySelectorAll not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am a total beginner at javascript and 
I am trying to make a modal image with these two pics. 
I am having trouble selecting the classes using querySelectorAll. 
It works if i put querySelectorAll('.pics1)[0];

but it does not work with querySelectorAll('.pics');

Would using document.getElementsByClassName be better?

```js
var modal= document.getElementById('myModal');
var image= document.querySelectorAll('.pics');
var modalpic= document.getElementById('img01');

image.addEventListener('click', function(){
   modal.style.display = "block";
    modalpic.src = this.src;  
});

var close= document.getElementById('close');


close.addEventListener('click', function(){
  modal.stlye.display="none";
});
```

```css
.modal{
  display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
  
}

.modalImage{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    align:center;
}

.pics{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pics:hover{
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#close{
  position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 10px;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#close:hover{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<img class="pics" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
    
<img class="pics" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg"/>

  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <img class="modalImgage" id="img01">
   </img>

 <span id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

</div>
```

Comment: because it is a HTML collection, it is not a single element.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns an HTML Collection-- if you want to add a listener to each image you'll have to iterate over the whole collection. It's working as expected.

Comment: if i put querySelectorAll('.pics1)[0]; ?? or if i put querySelectorAll('.pics)[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one button to click, place the buttons in another element and add the eventListener to that instead. When the click event is triggered, it will get fired not only on the element that wraps the buttons (`.frame`), but also the button you clicked. In order to get the actual button that you clicked, use the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var frame = document.getElementsByClassName('frame')[0];
var modalpic = document.getElementById('img01');

frame.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.className === 'pics') {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalpic.src = clicked.src;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.modalImage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
}
.pics {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  ;
  width: 20%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.pics:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  color: gold;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#close:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.frame {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<figure class='frame'>
  <img class="pics" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />

  <img class="pics" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" />
</figure>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <img class="modalImgage" id="img01">


  <span id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll(<something>)` returns a NodeList...sort of like an array in the sense that it is a collection of items. That's why adding `[0]` (or `[1]`, etc.) gives you a single element. In contrast, `querySelector(<selector>)` will just return a single item. Check the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) documentation for [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

If you are trying to get a single element and you use `querySelector` with a class that identifies more than one elements (such as your `class="pics"`), then `querySelector` will just return the first one. Thus, if you really do want to use a class like that, you might be better off using `querySelectorAll('pics')[0]`, etc. `querySelector` is more easily used with id's instead of classes, e.g. `querySelector('picA')` versus `querySelector('picB')` if you have them identified with `id="picA"` and `id="picB"`.

You ask if you should use `document.getElementsByClassName`. I suppose it's kind of up to you. However, I find that the above two methods (`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`) are very powerful and very useful, as you can use them in a variety of ways, e.g. with classes, with id's, with attributes, with combinations of all these...much more powerful than just being limited to a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this code:

```
<div id='div1'> 
  Content.. 
  <!-- content.. -->
  <br>
  <a id='close_btn'>click to Close</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('close_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
               document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
</script>
```